# Why isn't AngularJS binding to my array data?

Tags: angularjs

I have a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/grL95/9/

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Hello';
    $scope.myNumbers = [10, 20, 30];
    $scope.printNumbers = function() {
        console.log($scope.myNumbers);
    }
});
```

When I type in the input field, the text updates in 'real time'. However, when I hit print, the original numbers are being displayed in the console. How can I get the updated numbers to display?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on the arrays due to the **Javascript Scope** problem. You see, when you change the variable value, it is passing by value, meaning that any changes to the variable is overshadowed (the $scope inside the controller creates a new variables). To overcome this, you will need to use pass by reference so that the updates are reflected in the `console.log()`, as follow:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="num in myNumbers">
        <input type="text" ng-model="num.value" />
        <div>current scope: {{num.value}}</div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="printNumbers()">print</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Hello';
    $scope.myNumbers = [{value: 10},{value: 20},{value: 30}];
    $scope.printNumbers = function() {
        console.log($scope.myNumbers);
    }
});
```

**Result**

Try inputting 100 in column 1

[image]

this results: (in web inspector)

[image]

The array `[100, 20, 30]` shows as expected.

[PLAYGROUND](http://codepen.io/raunay/pen/uCLFt)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is loosing the reference when we are using ng-repeat for a value. If you can use a object array then it works fine.

```
    angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'Hello';
        $scope.myNumbers = [{val:10}, {val:20}, {val:30}];
        $scope.printNumbers = function() {
            console.log($scope.myNumbers);
        }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grL95/10/